# Question on the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding on Orbit-Stabilizer theorem and I came across with [gowers](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/group-actions-ii-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem/) excellent post explaining the intuition behind the theorem.

I will quote two statements from there,

> We’ve shown that for each $y\in O_x$ there are precisely $|S_x|$ elements of $G$ that take $x$ to $y$. But every element of $G$ takes $x$ to something in the orbit, so $|G|=|O_x||S_x|$, as we were trying to prove.

I don't understand why   "*every element of $G$ takes $x$ to something in the orbit"* implies *"so $|G|=|O_x||S_x|$".*

Moreover, continuing reading the **The real Proof 1.** he writes:

> ...the sets $S_{xy}$ with $y\in O_x$ form a partition of $G$. It follows that $|G|=|S_x||O_x|$.

So, another question is why the sets $S_{xy}$ form a partition of $G$(I could not see this) and why its implies $|G|=|S_x||O_x|$?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show the sets $S_{xy}$ form a partition of $G$.

"Each element of $G$ takes $x$ to something in the orbit $O_x$" implies $\bigcup_{y \in O_x} S_{xy} = G$. Explicitly, for any $g \in G$, we have $y:=gx \in O_x$, so $g \in S_{xy}$.

It remains to show the $S_{xy}$ are disjoint. This is clear: if $g$ lies in $S_{xy}$ and $S_{xy'}$, then $gx=y$ and $gx=y'$, so $y=y'$.